# Chrome Update Unstallation by appium

Tags: android, google-chrome, selenium, appium, uninstallation

I am using appium with selenium and chrome on android device for running tests,

After execution its uninstalling chrome's updates.

I don't want this to be done.

what command needs to be given?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `--full-reset` and use `--no-reset` option while starting an appium server

Comment: @ajay_bajaj if your issue has been solved then please accept above solution , else please comment if there is an issue